# How to check for a duplicate email address in PHP, considering Gmail (user.name+label@gmail.com)

Tags: php, gmail, duplicates, detection, email-validation

**How can I check for duplicate email addresses in PHP**, with the possibility of Gmail's automated labeler and punctuation in mind?

For example, I want these addressed to be detected as duplicates:

```
         username@gmail.com
        user.name@gmail.com
   username+label@gmail.com
  user.name+label@gmail.com
```

Despite what Daniel A. White claims: In Gmail, dots at random places before the '@' (and label) can be placed as much as you like. user.name@gmail.com and username@gmail.com are in fact the same user.

Comment: fyi a period is a unique part of an email address. i wouldnt exclude it as different.

Comment: Not for Gmail it isn't. These addresses are all the same: user.name@gmail.com, u.s.e.r.n.a.m.e@gmail.com, username@gmail.com

Comment: Try it if you don't believe me. :)

Comment: @Kriem: I have an gmail account and I sent an email to it from yahoo mail with a period (".") inserted into the email address (abcdef@gmail.com -> ab.cdef@gmail.com, doesn't reach my mailbox.

Comment: @o.k.w: I just tried gmail to gmail with a period between my gmail email and I got the email.

Comment: I got a bounced mail. Weird.. Maybe works only from gamil to gmail? Let me try :)

Comment: @Kriem: it works when I sent to my gmail address from my gmail account. ha!

Comment: Seems to work from hotmail to gmail.

Comment: There are some early Gmail users whose email must include a period and they will not get mail if sent to a version without. The period for all was later added. It's not blanket universal to mean the same user.

Comment: @e.c.ho: I didn't know that. So, my idea of unique ID'ing a person is flawed then I guess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$email_parts    = explode('@', $email);

// check if there is a "+" and return the string before
$before_plus    = strstr($email_parts[0], '+', TRUE);
$before_at      = $before_plus ? $before_plus : $email_parts[0];

// remove "."
$before_at      = str_replace('.', '', $before_at);

$email_clean    = $before_at.'@'.$email_parts[1];
```

Comment: You likely only want to remove the "."s from GMail addresses. As mentioned in the comments on the OP, most mail providers will recognise "." as a valid character, making the addresses different.

Comment: You are right if you are running this code on other addresses than the gmail ones. Just check after line 1 of my script 

if (in_array($email_parts[1], 'gmail.com', 'googlemail.com')) {
     // run the rest of the code...
}

Comment: powtac's addition has an error, the suffixes aren't within an array for use as the second parameter of the `in_array` function, should be `in_array($email_parts[1], array('gmail.com', 'googlemail.com'))`

Comment: I will post my working solution soon. Thanks @powtac, your example has given me an headway!

Comment: I can still defeat this by using: **name@gmail.com** and **name@googlemail.com**. Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42736222/1937344) for an _updated, working_ solution that I use!

Answer (score 2):

Strip the address to the basic form before comparing. Make a function `normalise()` that will strip the label, then remove all dots. Then you can compare the addresses via:

```
normalise(address1) == normalise(address2)
```

If you have to do it very often, save the addresses in the normalised form too, so you don't have to convert them back too often.

Comment: I agree totally! Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42736222/1937344) for the `normalize_email()` function that I use.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is an improvement on @powtac's answer. I needed this function to defeat multiple signups from same person using gmail.

```
if ( ! function_exists('normalize_email'))
{
    /**
     * to normalize emails to a base format, especially for gmail
     * @param $email
     * @return string
     */
    function normalize_email($email) {
        // ensure email is lowercase because of pending in_array check, and more...
        $email = strtolower($email);
        $parts    = explode('@', $email);

        // normalize gmail addresses
        if (in_array($parts[1], ['gmail.com', 'googlemail.com'])) {
            // check if there is a "+" and return the string before then remove "."
            $before_plus    = strstr($parts[0], '+', TRUE);
            $before_at      = str_replace('.', '', $before_plus ? $before_plus : $parts[0]);

            // ensure only @gmail.com addresses are used
            $email    = $before_at.'@gmail.com';
        }

        return $email;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would be better titled "How to normalize gmail addresses in PHP, considering (user.name+label@gmail.com)"

You have two technical solutions above.  I'll go a different route and ask why you're trying to do this.  It doesn't feel right to me.  Are you trying to prevent someone registering multiple times at your site using different e-mail addresses?  This will only prevent a specialized case of that.

I have my own domain, example.com, and any e-mail that goes to any address at that domain goes to my single mailbox.  Do you, now, want to put a check to normalize anything at my example.com to a single address on your end?

By the [official e-mail address format](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/822addr.html), those addresses you are trying to match as the same are different.

Comment: I have a nice in-the-wild example of why you'd want to do this - I've had someone signing up for an account, and so far they have used over 10,000 variants of 5 gmail addresses. As to what possible benefit they get from this, I really don't know!

Answer (score 1):

Email address parsing is really, really hard to do correctly, without breaking things and annoying users..

First, I would question if you really need to do this? Why do you have multiple email addresses, with different sub-addresses?

If you are sure you need to do this, first read [rfc0822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt), then modify [this email address parsing regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) to extract all parts of the email, and recombine them excluding the label..

Slightly more.. practically, the Email Address wikipedia page has a section on this part of the address format, [Sub-addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Sub-addressing).

The code powtac posted looks like it should work - as long as you're not using it in an automated manner to delete accounts or anything, it should be fine.

Note that the "automated labeler" isn't a GMail specific feature, Gmail simply popularised it.. Other mail servers support this feature, some using `+`  as the separator, others using `-`. If you are going to special-case spaces in GMail addresses, remember to consider the `googlemail.com` domain also

Comment: I love this answer and asked a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42760794/1937344). I need answers!

Answer (score 1):

I have extended  Zend Validator like this.

```
<?php
class My_Validate_EmailAddress extends Zend_Validate_EmailAddress
{
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $valid = parent::isValid($value);
        if ($valid
                && in_array($this->_hostname, array('gmail.com', 'googlemail.com'))
                && substr_count($this->_localPart, '.') > 1) {
            $this->_error(parent::INVALID_HOSTNAME);
            $valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

Email with more than one "dot" symbol in gmail address are considered invalid. For some cases this is not logical solution, but that works for me.

Comment: > Email with more than one "dot" symbol in gmail address are considered invalid.
Do you have any evidence of this?

Answer (score -1):

```
function normalize($input) {
     $input = str_replace('.', '', $input);
     $pattern = '/\+(\w+)@/';
     return preg_replace($pattern, '@', $input);
}
```

Comment: `$input = str_replace('.', '', $input);` seems a bit brutal. It will make "bob@ex.ample.com" and "bob@example.com" the same..

Comment: Very brutal. You should first check if it's a @gmail.com or @googlemail.com, then do the `str_replace` on the LHS... etc.