# Check if account with such email address already registered (including dots, etc)

Tags: php, validation, duplicates

I read a lot of questions regarding checking if there area identical emails stored in database. However none of those solutions considered a situation when an email provider, for example google, allows users to have dots in their account names. For example `username@gmail.com` equals `user.name@gmail.com`.

I understand I can strip dots and check them like this, is it a good idea?

But I believe there are other things that need to be considered here.

Help me check if I already have a given email in database with consideration for dots and other extra factors.

**UPDATE**
This is the way I check if there already is an email address.

```
public function isemail($email)
{
    $qw = $this->registry->dbi->prepare("SELECT `email` FROM `".PRE."membership` WHERE `email`=?;")->execute($email)->results();
    if (empty($qw)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Problem is that for example `onetwo@gmail.com` is different than `one.two@gmail.com` because there is a dot. Some emails allow dots to be for same accounts and some do not. How should I behave?

**SIMILAR SOLUTION**

Solution to a similar question can be found here

[How to check for a duplicate email address in PHP, considering Gmail (user.name+label@gmail.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586389/how-to-check-for-a-duplicate-email-address-in-php-considering-gmail-user-name)

Comment: Why are duplicate addresses a problem?

Comment: Because it's a registration system, where there has to be one email per login.

Comment: periods are valid in the local part of the email address, rfc5322,rfc5321. me@host.tld and m.e@host.tld should be considered different; adding a unique constraint on the email address should suffice. (if a host chooses to map m.e@ and me@ to the same user that is out of your control; it could just as well choose to map me@ and mu@ to the same user/account)

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for great information

Comment: @tmpmember: "How should I behave?" is the question?  That's entirely subjective and depends completely on your own project requirements.  Many email services do support dots and routes all emails to the same address - dots or no dots, like google and I think yahoo.  Some email services may not, and consider these two separate email accounts.  You'd have to get the rules from all email services out there to determine this, which I'm sure number in the several hundreds or thousands.  Best just forget about the dot problem, and go with additional checks against names, addresses, or other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything special about dots in the email address. Just do a SELECT query searching for the email address and if you get 1 or more rows back, then you know it's a duplicate. I suspect your issue may have something to do with the way you're constructing the query. Try passing the email to [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) before including it in the query. If that doesn't help then post the relevant portion of your code so we can better help troubleshoot.

Comment: I use mysqli and I think my queries are correct. I check for similar usernames and it works fine. What I'm talking about is that `name.surname@gmail.com` is same as `namesurname@gmail.com` and registrants can add these emails on my website, while owner is one and the same. I will post my code now. thanks.

Comment: Technically speaking the email address with dots and without are two separate email addresses. Some email providers might consider them to be equivalent (it seems this is the case for Gmail) but it's definitely not standard behavior. So if you want to account for this possibility then you should specifically check the domain to see if it's Gmail, etc. and then strip out the dots just in those cases (do `explode('@', $email)` first and just do `str_replace` on the part before the `@`)

Comment: I just found this one `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586389/how-to-check-for-a-duplicate-email-address-in-php-considering-gmail-user-name` Check it if you're interested. It offers a nice solutioon

Comment: If you wanted it to be more generic then it should be based on user confirmation, e.g. "An email address very similar to what you entered (first.last@test.com) is already registered. Is this also your address? If so, click here to log in. Forgot your password? ..."

Comment: @tmpmember That's a good solution as long as you include the check for gmail.com as one of the commenters there mentioned.