# mail clients that support the "automated labeler" email address format (eg: name+label@gmail.com)

Tags: php, email, duplicates, gmail, detection

I need to know which mail clients support the "automated labeler" email address format.

From research I have found only one: Gmail. They support labeled email addresses like:

- name+label_1@gmail.com
- name+label_2@gmail.com
- etc.

The above emails are unique but reference **name@gmail.com** with unique labels.

Follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1586389/1937344) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1586496/1937344) for more insight on this topic.

> Note that the "automated labeler" isn't a GMail specific feature, Gmail simply popularised it.. Other mail servers support this feature, some using `+` as the separator, others using `-`.

Comment: **This is to those voting to close this question.** Please check the *linked question*. The answer to this question will help protect websites that do not want duplicate signups from same emails. Thank you!